how to read data from UR10 robot via TCP in javascript
I am trying to read data from an UR10 robot, and I dont know how to process it.
This is what I get from the code below:
Connected to UR10 robot
--------------------raw data ---------------------
<Buffer 00 00 00 37 14 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff fe 03 09 55 52 43 6f 6e 74 72 6f 6c 03 0f 00 00 00 07 00 00 00 00 30 36 2d 30 38 2d 32 30 32 31 2c 20 30 38 3a ... 29 more bytes>
-----------------data decoded ------------------
n=79
dataIn:7ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿþ       URControl06-08-2021, 08:31:17ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿþ
w&w(
(node:14184) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
(Use node --trace-deprecation ... to show where the warning was created)
Connection to UR10 robot closed
const net = require('net');
const HOST = '192.168.1.50'; 
const PORT = 30002; 

const client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(PORT, HOST, () => {
    console.log('Connected to UR10 robot');    
});

client.on('data', (data) => {

    console.log("--------------------raw data ---------------------");
    console.log(data);
    console.log("-------------------------------------------------");

    console.log("-----------------data decoded ------------------");
    var bytes = new Buffer(data, "ascii");
    var n = bytes.length;
    var dataIn = "";
    console.log('n=' + n);
    for (d = 0; d < n; d++) {
        var c = bytes[d];
        var c = String.fromCharCode(bytes[d]);
        dataIn = dataIn + c;
    }
    console.log("dataIn:" + dataIn); // this gives that buffer


    var dataInX = socket_read_ascii_float(data);
    console.log("dataInX:" + dataInX); // seems to decode, but not very useful

    client.destroy(); // Close the connection after receiving data
});

client.on('close', () => {
    console.log('Connection to UR10 robot closed');
});


It is not clear to me what you problem is:  1. do you get a different behavior than expected - please describe what you expect and why (like pointers to some documentation). 2. Or do you have no idea how communication with the peer should work in the first place - please check documentation (if available) or ask for help in reverse engineering the protocol. The latter would be more on-topic and [reverseengineering.se] then.

there are some posts on UR forums, like this below, but that is for C# and includes a number of dependencies.
https://www.universal-robots.com/articles/ur/interface-communication/tcpip-socket-communication-via-urscript/
